# How to vertical align an inline-block in a line of text?

Tags: html, vertical-alignment, css

I want to create an inline-block that will take on some unknown width and height. (It'll have a table inside it with content dynamically generated).  Further, the inline-block should be placed inside a line of text, such as "my text (BLOCK HERE)".  To make it look pretty, **I'm trying to make the block be vertically centered in the line**.  So if the block looks like this:

```
TOP
MIDDLE
BOTTOM
```

Then the line of text will read: "My text ( [MIDDLE] )" (with TOP and BOTTOM above and below the line)

Here's what I have so far.

#### CSS

```
.example {
  background-color: #0A0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="example">TOP<br />MIDDLE<br />BOTTOM</div>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Maybe draw it up and post an image of what you want. Maybe it's me, but I have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

```css
code {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text <code>A<br />B<br />C<br />D</code> continues afterward.</p>
```

Tested and works in Safari 5 and IE6+.

Comment: I used your solution on a similar problem, but I'm trying to center a CSS Triangle. However, it's not totally centered. What can I add to your recipe to make it totally centered?

Comment: @Imray Position: relative ?

Answer (score 24):

`display: inline-block` is your friend you just need all three parts of the construct - before, the "block", after - to be one, then you can vertically align them all to the middle:

#### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/kaHek/)

(it looks like your picture anyway ;))

**CSS:**

```
p, div {
  display: inline-block; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
p, div {
  display: inline !ie7; /* hack for IE7 and below */
}

table {
  background: #000; 
  color: #fff; 
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-weight: bold; margin: 0 10px;
}

td {
  padding: 5px; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>some text</p> 
<div>
  <table summary="">
  <tr><td>A</td></tr>
  <tr><td>B</td></tr>
  <tr><td>C</td></tr>
  <tr><td>D</td></tr>
  </table>
</div> 
<p>continues afterwards</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Loosely related but worth mentioning we can make the text vertically oriented with CSS

[writing-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

[text-orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation)

```
div {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: upright;
}


<div>A B C D</div>
```