# Margin-top/bottom not works the to margin-left/right in a sample

Tags: html, css, margin

I am new to HTML & CSS.
I have tried the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Center</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="div1" style="width:300;background-color:olive">
        <div id="div2" style="width:100px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color:gray"></div>
    </div>  
</body>

</html>
```

The "div2" is in centered horizontally.

Then I change the width to height & margin-left/right to margin-top/bottom. (the code below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Center</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="div1" style="height:100px;background-color:olive">
        <div id="div2" style="height:20px; margin-top:auto; margin-bottom:auto; background-color:gray"></div>
    </div>  
</body>

</html>
```

It is not centered vertically as I expected.

Any can help me to explain this, why they don't have the same behaviors?
Thanks,
Hoang

Comment: Vertical centering isn't so easy as horizontal. `auto` do nothing with `margin-top/bottom`.

Comment: Do you know the reason why it not have the same behavior as the logic?

Comment: I'm not the author of CSS spec, but as a developer I've never need to center vertically by this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`margin-auto` only works on horizontal margin. i.e `margin-left and right`.

There is no way you can set vertical margin to auto. instead you can make it an inline block and set it vertically middle. read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6191011/3556874)

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin):

```
margin: auto;  /* box is horizontally centered, 0 margin on top and bottom */
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html style="height:100%">
<head>
<title>Center</title>
</head>

<body style="height:100%; width:100%">
    <div style="display:table; width:100%; height:100%">
        <div id="div1" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle">
            <div id="div2" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;height:20px; margin:0 auto; background-color:gray">Text is vertical alignment</div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>

</html>
```