# Margin-top and Margin-bottom not working when I try to center vertically

Tags: jquery, html, css

trying to center my red block in the middle of the webpage, and the footer block at the bottom of the red, and finally the white one between the top of the red block and the footer. Margin-top isn't working for some reason, although left and right are..

Copied my code from a local file so there are some dead links, but I think they're irrelevant on CodePen as it's still showing up the same.

```
#container {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border:solid black;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:red;
    height:650px;
    width:850px;
    padding:1px;
}

#container.hover {
}

.wrapper {
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    height:450px;
    width:650px;
    background-color:white;
    border:solid black;
    border-width:1px;
}

#grid {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    background-color:white;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    border: solid black;
    border-width:.5px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    padding:.5px .5px .5px .5px;
}

#foot {
    display:block;
    height:90px;
    border:solid black;
    border-width: 2px;
    margin-top:auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Kennpow/pen/bpJRvw

Comment: Have you tried `margin:auto;` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Margin-top/bottom not works the to margin-left/right in a sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960204/margin-top-bottom-not-works-the-to-margin-left-right-in-a-sample)

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/6775273/1028949

Answer (score 1):

`margin-top:auto` and `margin-bottom:auto` doesn't work the way you think they will compared to `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto`.

`margin-top:auto` and `margin-bottom:auto` will be computed as 0, while `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` will be computed as equal margins. I think it has to do with how the browser renders the page.

From https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#normal-block:

> If 'margin-top', or 'margin-bottom' are 'auto', their used value is 0.

From https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#blockwidth:

> If both 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' are 'auto', their used values
>   are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
#container: { display:flex; }
```

EDIT/ADDITION:

Add another wrapper around the `#container' and give it these settings:

```
#wrap_all {
  display:flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

(Same, edited) codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZLvpj

Comment: This works great fox centering inside the box. Thanks! 
Now I need to center the whole thing inside the webpage.

Comment: @KennyPower please see my updated answer and also updated codepen.