# vertically center inline content

Tags: html, css

I have text and image content/divs that are aligned. But I want them to be centred vertically with each other as well.

html

```
<div class="cell"><a href="...'</a></div>
<div class="separate"></div>
<div class="cell"><a href="...'</a></div>
<div class="separate"></div>
<div class="cell"><a href="...'</a></div>
```

css

```
.cell, .separate {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.separate {
  width: 2px; height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932201/how-to-vertical-align-an-inline-block-in-a-line-of-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To this rule, add `vertical-align: middle;`:

```
.cell, .separate {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: didn't think it was that easy. Good browser support?

Comment: yes - inline-block is nothing fancy...

Comment: Appology, I meant does vertical-align: middle; have good support

Comment: yes, see here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp - scroll down a bit to see browser support: Since IE 4, Chrome 1, Firefox 1, Safari 1, Opera 4...

Answer (score 0):

One way to vertically align content is using line height. This method only works for one line of text though:

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Text here</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#child {
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

This can be extended for images too:

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <img src="image.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent {
    line-height: 200px;
}

#parent img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You can read about other methods to vertically center content here: http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 0):

You can vertically align inline content with `vertical-align`

```css
.cell, .separate {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.separate {
  width: 2px; height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">asdf</div>
<div class="separate"></div>
<div class="cell">asdf</div>
<div class="separate"></div>
<div class="cell">asdf</div>
```